# String to array in javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose if i have a string of values Active Stock Master Portfolio, BlackRock Advantage Global Fund, Inc. , BlackRock Advantage Large Cap Core Portfolio where "BlackRock Advantage Global Fund, Inc." is a complete one string.

```
var fn = rowData.FundNames.split(',');
            fn = fn.sort();
            //console.log(fn);
            for (var j = 0; j < fn.length; j++) {
                if (fFootNoteTxtArr.length > 0) {
                    for (i = 0; i < fFootNoteTxtArr.length; i++) {

                        var abcd = String(fFootNoteTxtArr[i]);
                        t = abcd.split(' ** ');

                        var xyz = String(fFootNoteSymbolArr[i]);
                        s = xyz.split(' ** ');

                        //console.log(fn[j].trim()+'----------'+t[0].substring(1));
                        //console.log('='+fn[j].trim()+'==TTT----------'+t[0]+'='+t[1]);
                        //console.log('SSS=='+s[0]+'----------'+s[1]+'=');
                        if (fn[j].trim() == t[0]) {
                            if (s[1] == undefined)
                                s[1] = '';
                            var tooltipText = s[1] + ' ' + t[1];
                            if (j == fn.length - 1 && i == fFootNoteTxtArr.length - 1) {
                                var fundTxtTmp = t[0] + '' + s[1] + '';
                            }
                            else {
                                var fundTxtTmp = t[0] + '' + s[1] + ',&nbsp;';
                            }
                            //fn_all[j] = '<td onmouseout="hideGridTooltip(this)" onmouseover="showGridTooltip(this,\''+tooltipText+'\',event)" style="font-size: 12px; display: inline;">'+fundTxtTmp+'<span class="gridTooltipClass">'+ tooltipText +'</span></td>';
                            fn_all[j] = '<span onmouseout="hideGridTooltip(this)" onmouseover="showGridTooltip(this,\'' + tooltipText + '\',event)" style="font-size: 12px; display: inline;">' + fundTxtTmp + '<span class="gridTooltipClass">' + tooltipText + '</span></span>';


                        }
                        else {
                            if (j == fn.length - 1 && i == fFootNoteTxtArr.length - 1) {
                                //fn_all[j] = '<td>'+fn[j]+''+'</td>';
                                fn_all[j] = '' + fn[j] + '' + '';
                            }
                            else {
                                //fn_all[j] = '<td>'+fn[j]+',&nbsp;'+'</td>';
                                fn_all[j] = '' + fn[j] + ',&nbsp;' + '';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //fn_all = '<td>'+fn+'</td>';
                    fn_all[0] = '<span>' + fn + '</span>';
                }

            }
```

If the above code is checked at last due to that comma those two are printed separately on the screen which should not...can any one help me with this.

Comment: consider using a csv parser

Comment: how should we do that sir please help me i am new to programming

Comment: It's ambiguous.  "BAGF, Inc., BRALCCP" looks like 3 items if you use only commas as delimiters between items.  You'd have to have some kind of a special case to handle `, Inc.` as being part of the previous value.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to use a csv parser. Having said that, here's a little recycled code of mine for parsing string assuming no `"` in between other `"`

```js
var str = 'Active Stock Master Portfolio, "BlackRock Advantage Global Fund, Inc.", BlackRock Advantage Large Cap Core Portfolio';

function tokenize(str) {
  state = "normal";
  tokens = [];
  current = "";
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    c = str.charAt(i);

    if (state == "normal") {
      if (c == ',') {
        if (current) {
          tokens.push(current);
          current = "";
        }
        continue;
      }
      if (c == '"') {
        state = "quotes";
        current = "";
        continue;
      }
      current += c;
    }
    if (state == "quotes") {
      if (c == '"') {
        state = "normal";
        tokens.push(current);
        current = "";
        continue;
      }
      current += c;
    }
  }
  if (current) {
    tokens.push(current);
    current = "";
  }
  return tokens;
}

var result = tokenize(str);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help sir.  And i even tried the same by passing fn= tokenize(str) i don't why the values are coming correctly but suddenly it is getting missplaced

Comment: What is getting misplaced?

Comment: here in the code you wrote you took "" for the word that is having comma but i am getting data from the server. So how can we apply "" for that sir.